# Is there a way to align commas in initializer list using clang format?

Tags: clang-format

For example, if it is possible to format

```
static const Field field[] = {
    { "c_name", "integer", "not null" },
    { "c_id", "varchar(50)", "not null" },
};
```

to

```
static const Field field[] = {
    { "c_name", "integer",     "not null" },
    { "c_id",   "varchar(50)", "not null" },
};
```

using clang-format?

Answer (score 3):

I have searched a lot. The only solution I found is formatting manually. Turn off the clang format, format the code manually and then turn it on using inline comment.

```
// clang-format off
static const Field field[] = {
    { "c_name", "integer",     "not null" },
    { "c_id",   "varchar(50)", "not null" },
};
// clang-format on
```